# Playing wav files with python simpleaudio produces: SimpleaudioError: Unable to start queue. -- CODE: -66681

Tags: python, wav, playback, simpleaudioengine

```
import simpleaudio as sa

wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file('path to wav file/test.wav')
play_obj = wave_obj.play()
play_obj.wait_done()  # Wait until sound has finished playing
```

The code was working until I installed a few packages (firebase, Crypto, python_jwt, cryptodome, pycrypto).  Now it produces:

```
SimpleaudioError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-15372821820f> in <module>
      2 
      3 wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file('/Users/mohamed/Files/IBM Watson TTS/Segments/output.wav')
----> 4 play_obj = wave_obj.play()
      5 play_obj.wait_done()  # Wait until sound has finished playing

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/simpleaudio/shiny.py in play(self)
     18     def play(self):
     19         return play_buffer(self.audio_data, self.num_channels,
---> 20                            self.bytes_per_sample, self.sample_rate)
     21 
     22     @classmethod

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/simpleaudio/shiny.py in play_buffer(audio_data, num_channels, bytes_per_sample, sample_rate)
     59 def play_buffer(audio_data, num_channels, bytes_per_sample, sample_rate):
     60     play_id = _sa._play_buffer(audio_data, num_channels, bytes_per_sample,
---> 61                                sample_rate)
     62     return PlayObject(play_id)

SimpleaudioError: Unable to start queue. -- CODE: -66681
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as stated in the op's answer - it was a matter of rebooting his computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the computer fixed it.